# iOS6 and Bluetooth OBDII Adapters

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Does anyone know of a OBDII Bluetooth adapter that works with iPhone? I would be developing an application for the iPhone 5 where Bluetooth 4.0 is supported. I have found several adapters, but they do not support Bluetooth 4.0.

I am aware that Apple restricts Bluetooth development for Bluetooth versions before 4.0. Is there anyway to work around this so I could use older versions of Bluetooth? I am open to Jailbreaking the device if needed.

WiFi adapters are not an option.

Thanks

Comment: I moved this over to Ask Different, because it's more a question about hardware compatibility. While not out yet, something like Automatic: http://www.automatic.com might do the trick. It will be a Bluetooth LE device, although I'm not sure if they'll give you full ODB-II access.

Comment: http://gopointtech.com/  they make a Bluetooth OBD-II device for iPhone. I don't know if it's BT 4.0 but why should that matter? Bluetooth is backwards compatible.

Comment: Did you get something to work? I am also trying to build a quick project, that would only need really simple data from the car, but a cheap adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Dash ( http://drivewithdash.com/ ) is promising a Bluetooth 4.0 ODB-II module, but it's not available yet; it's a Kickstarter project as of this writing ( http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/shred444/drive-with-dash ).

Also take a look at Automatic ( http://www.automatic.com/ ), as Brad Larson mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I am beta-testing [Automatic](http://www.automatic.com/) right now. It isn't exactly a ODBII device, as much as it is a  driving assistant. It does log ODBII codes, and allows you to clear the vehicle's computer when one comes up.

However, it also determines when you do hard brakes, hard acceleration, and when you exceed 70 MPH, effectively trying to coach you into better driving habits. It also logs your trips, gives you your gas mileage, gas cost, and when GPS is used, your complete trip is logged on a map, with time started and stopped.

Answer (score 1):

the LELink device by 
http://www.outdoor-apps.com
does work with iPhone.
I am also working on an application and 
have so far issued an "ATZ" command and 
got back "ELM v1.5" 
using ios core bluetooth library.
You need a 4s or later iPhone.

Comment: Can you please add more details of your work, some sample code may be... Thanks :)

Comment: I created an [iPhone app] (http://ezobd.com/)